# Django class-based "method_splitter" - passing 2 slugs as model name and field value, respectively

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I want to create a ["method_splitter"](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08.html) equivalent using class-based views in order to remove some hard-coding in my URL confs.

I would like to have the following URL's:

```
ListView: http://mysite.com/<model_name>/
DetailView: http://mysite.com/<model_name>/<field_value>/
```

where the query for the ListView would be:

```
<model_name>.objects.all()
```

and the queryset for the DetailView would be:

```
<model_name>.objects.get(<field>=<field_Value>)
```

Currently, my views work as a result of some hardcoding in the url conf, but I would like to find an elegant solution that can scale.

My solution does not give a 404, but displays nothing:

**views.py**

```
class ListOrDetailView(View):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        setattr(self, key, value)

try: #If/Else instead?
    def goToDetailView(self, **kwargs):
        m = get_list_or_404(self.kwargs['model']) #Is this even needed?
        return DetailView(model=self.kwargs['model'], slug=self.kwargs['slug'], template_name='detail.html', context_object_name='object')

except: #If/Else instead?
    def goToListView(self, **kwargs):
        q = get_object_or_404(self.kwargs['model'], slug=self.kwargs['slug']) #Is this even needed?
        return ListView(model=self.kwargs['model'], template_name='list.html', context_object_name='object_list',)
```

**urls.py of MyApp**

```
url(r'^(?P<model>[\w]+)/?(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', ListOrDetailView.as_view()),
```

Comment: I would separate this view into two views. It's bad design in my opinion. Is there a reason for this tightknitting?

Comment: I'm open to splitting it up. Could you post an example of how you'd pass the slug to the ListView/DetailView? I can test it and accept if it works.

Comment: How do you plan to restrict the models that people have access to? can anyone lookup any model by any field?

Comment: @Thomas - that's a good point. in a manageable app, it may be worthwhile just to do the restricting in the urlconf.  how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

As limelights said, this is a horrible design pattern; the whole point of Django is separation of models and views. If you fear that you might have to write a lot of repetitive code to cover all your different models, trust me that it's not much of an issue with class-based views. Essentially, you need to write this for each of your models you wish to expose like this:

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^my_model/$', MyModelListView.as_view(), name="mymodel_list"),
    url(r'^my_model/(?P<field_value>\w+)/$', MyModelDetailView.as_view(), name="mymodel_detail"),
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class MyModelListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel


class MyModelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        field_value = self.kwargs.get("field_value")
        return self.model.objects.filter(field=field_value)
```